# Django audio recording issue: receiving Bad Request error

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, bad-request

I am new to Django and also my first time building an application. I am building an audio journaling application with Django. What I am doing here is a recorder. When user press the recorder button, it will direct to record.html with four buttons, Start, Pause, Resume and Stop. When the user finished recording and hit the Stop button, it will save a audio file (wav). However, I have receive a bad request error and the audio file is not created.

The code:

**views.py**

```
@login_required  
def record_audio(request):
  print("11",request.method)
  print("1")
  if request.method == 'POST':
    print("2")
    if 'blob' not in request.POST:
      print(request.POST)
      print("3")
      return HttpResponseBadRequest('Missing audio-blob parameter')

    print("4")
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    print("5")
    filename = f"{request.user.username}_{now}.wav"
    print("6")
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename)

    # Save the audio file to the server
    print("7")
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(request.POST['blob'].encode())

    return HttpResponse(status=204)  # Return a 204 No Content response
else:
    print("8")
    return render(request, 'recording/record.html')
```

**updated version of views.py** - but still doesn't solve the problem

```
@login_required   
@ensure_csrf_cookie
@require_http_methods({"GET","POST"})
def record_audio(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'recording/record.html')
    blob= request.FILES.get("blob", None)
    if blob is None:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Missing audio-blob parameter")

    now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    filename = f"{request.user.username}_{now}.wav"
    filepath = Path.joinpath(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "recordings",filename)
     
    with open(filepath, 'wb') as audio_file:
        for chunk in blob.chunks():
            audio_file.write(chunk)

    return HttpResponse(status=HTTPStatus.NO_CONTENT)
```

**record.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Recorder</h1>

<section class="experiment" >
  <br>
  <h3>
    Send Message: Speech to text
  </h3>
  <button id="start-recording">Start</button>
  <button id="pause-recording" disabled>Pause</button>
  <button id="resume-recording" disabled>Resume</button>
  <button id="stop-recording" disabled>Stop</button>
</section>

<section class="experiment">
    <div id="audios-container"></div>
</section> 

{% include "chat_script.html" %}
<script src="https://cdn.WebRTC-Experiment.com/MediaStreamRecorder.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.12.3.js' %}"></script>
<!-- <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>  -->
<!-- <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>  -->

  <!-- <div>
    <audio id="audio-player" controls></audio>
  </div> -->

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

`path('record-audio/',views.record_audio,name="record_audio"),`

**chat_script.html**

```
<script>
    function captureUserMedia(mediaConstraints, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints).then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback);
    }

var mediaConstraints = {
    audio: true
};

document.querySelector('#start-recording').onclick = function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    captureUserMedia(mediaConstraints, onMediaSuccess, onMediaError);
};

document.querySelector('#stop-recording').onclick = function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    mediaRecorder.stream.stop();

    while (audiosContainer.firstChild) {
        audiosContainer.removeChild(audiosContainer.firstChild);
    }

    document.querySelector('#pause-recording').disabled = true;
    document.querySelector('#start-recording').disabled = false;
};

document.querySelector('#pause-recording').onclick = function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    mediaRecorder.pause();

    document.querySelector('#resume-recording').disabled = false;
};

document.querySelector('#resume-recording').onclick = function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    mediaRecorder.resume();

    document.querySelector('#pause-recording').disabled = false;
};

// {#document.querySelector('#save-recording').onclick = function() {#}
// {#    this.disabled = true;#}
// {#    mediaRecorder.save();#}
// {##}
// {#    // alert('Drop WebM file on Chrome or Firefox. Both can play entire file. VLC player or other players may not work.');#}
// {#};#}

var mediaRecorder;

function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');

    audio = mergeProps(audio, {
        controls: true,
        muted: true
    });
    audio.srcObject = stream;
    audio.play();

    audiosContainer.appendChild(audio);
    audiosContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));

    mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.stream = stream;


    mediaRecorder.recorderType = StereoAudioRecorder;
    mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'audio/wav';


    // don't force any mimeType; use above "recorderType" instead.
    // mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'audio/webm'; // audio/ogg or audio/wav or audio/webm

    mediaRecorder.audioChannels = true;
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(blob) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.target = '_blank';
        a.innerHTML = 'Open Recorded Audio No. ' + (index++) + ' (Size: ' + bytesToSize(blob.size) + ') Time Length: ' + getTimeLength(timeInterval);

        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // {#audiosContainer.appendChild(a);#}
        // {#audiosContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));#}

         function getCookie(name) {
                var cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cookieValue;
            }

            var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/record-audio/', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("MyCustomHeader", "Put anything you need in here, like an ID");
            xhr.send(blob);
    };

    var timeInterval = 10000;
    if (timeInterval) timeInterval = parseInt(timeInterval);
    else timeInterval = 5 * 1000;

    // get blob after specific time interval
    mediaRecorder.start(timeInterval);

    document.querySelector('#stop-recording').disabled = false;
    document.querySelector('#pause-recording').disabled = false;
    document.querySelector('#save-recording').disabled = false;
}

function onMediaError(e) {
    console.error('media error', e);
}

var audiosContainer = document.getElementById('audios-container');
var index = 1;

function bytesToSize(bytes) {
    var k = 1000;
    var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
    if (bytes === 0) return '0 Bytes';
    var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k)), 10);
    return (bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toPrecision(3) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}

function getTimeLength(milliseconds) {
    var data = new Date(milliseconds);
    return data.getUTCHours() + " hours, " + data.getUTCMinutes() + " minutes and " + data.getUTCSeconds() + " second(s)";
}

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    document.querySelector('#start-recording').disabled = false;
};

window.useThisGithubPath = 'streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder';
```

`

**chat_script.html code from: https://github.com/ehtisham91/Django-Speech-to-text-Chat **

I have try to add some print statement in the views.py record_audio function. And it gives me this:

11 GET

1

8

[27/Mar/2023 16:12:23] "GET /record-audio/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13124

11 GET

1

8

[27/Mar/2023 16:12:39] "GET /record-audio/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13115

11 POST

1

2

<QueryDict: {}>

3

Bad Request: /record-audio/

[27/Mar/2023 16:12:42] "POST /record-audio/ HTTP/1.1" 400 28

I tried to figure it out but still didn't fix it.

Updated:
I tried to download the audio directly from the chat_script.html, it works fine. The audio is downloaded . the problem here is I can't download it from the back-end. Because I am actually trying to make it upload to the database after I solve the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You backend wait for a parameter named blob.

```
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/record-audio/', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("MyCustomHeader", "Put anything you need in here, like an ID");
    xhr.send('blob='+blob);
```

Comment: I still get bad request

11 GET
1
8
[27/Mar/2023 16:57:22] "GET /record-audio/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13131
[27/Mar/2023 16:57:22] "GET /static/css/journal.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
11 POST
1
2
<QueryDict: {}>
3
Bad Request: /record-audio/
[27/Mar/2023 16:57:33] "POST /record-audio/ HTTP/1.1" 400 28

Comment: The query dict is empty. Also is there an empty post request. Can you check if the variable blob in the js-part is empty?

Comment: May I know how to check?

Comment: before xhr.send() write console.log(blob) and refresh the page. Then you see it in the console from your Browser. If you dont know how to open the console, take a look here: https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/

Comment: Blob
size
: 
401452
type
: 
"audio/wav"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Blob
arrayBuffer
: 
ƒ arrayBuffer()
size
: 
(...)
slice
: 
ƒ slice()
stream
: 
ƒ stream()
text
: 
ƒ text()
type
: 
(...)
constructor
: 
ƒ Blob()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
: 
"Blob"
get size
: 
ƒ size()
get type
: 
ƒ type()
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object